Why should I add dependencies of logging project(using serilog) in ASP.NET Web API project, else configuration is not building correctly
I created a class library project (.NET Framework 4.8) for logging using Serilog. In this logging project I installed all other nuget packages required like Serilog.Sinks.File, Serilog.Settings.Configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.
Now I referenced this project in an ASP.NET Web API project (on .NET 4.8) and added a serilog.json file in this project which contains configuration for Serilog:
{
    "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                    "path": "log\\log_new.txt",
                    "rollingInterval": "Day"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Code to setup container
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("serilog.json").Build();

LoggerConfiguration config = new LoggerConfiguration()
                                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration);

_logger = config.CreateLogger();

When I try log from the Web API project, the logger configuration is not setup properly. It is initialized with default configuration and not the configuration I provided in serilog.json.
Then I tried installing Serilog.Sinks.File, Serilog.Settings.Configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json in the Web API project and the logger got initialized with correct configuration.
Why I should add all these dependencies in Web API project from Nuget package manager?
I should not have to install Serilog and related packages in Web API project from NPM. They should automatically get copied from output folder of logging project to output folder of Web API project...
